# Inconsistent currency symbol in iOS17

Tags: swift

In iOS17, this bit of code sometimes prints `$`, sometimes prints `US$`:

```
func getSymbolForCurrencyCode(code: String) -> String? {
        let result = Locale.availableIdentifiers.map { Locale(identifier: $0) }.first { $0.currencyCode == code }
        return result?.currencySymbol
    }
```

This used to work fine up prior iOS17. Since `currencyCode` was deprecated in iOS16, I also tried changing the code to:

```
func getSymbolForCurrencyCode(code: String) -> String? {
        let result = Locale.availableIdentifiers.map { Locale(identifier: $0) }.first { $0.identifier == code }
        return result?.currencySymbol
    }
```

But this comes back `nil`.

How can I consistently have it print `$`?

Comment: What is wrong about returning `US$` as currency symbol? That's completely correct.
Why do you randomly pick a first `Locale` instead of using a specific locale, e.g. the US-POSIX locale?

Comment: Currency symbol depends on the locale. E.g., `$` in canada can be ambiguous

Comment: The first bit of code uses `$0.currencyCode == "USD"`. The 2nd bit of code uses `$0.identifier == "USD"`.

The only thing that's wrong with this inconsistency is screen space. This is on a widget somewhere, and the extra `US` in the result messes up the visual placement/formatting.

Comment: @ppp If you want `USD` to be always represented with `$` then don't use `Locale` at all, or use a specific Locale. Currently you are just randomly picking a locale identifier, therefore the result must be inconsistent.

Comment: @ColouredPanda I hear you but why does the result differ on the same device?

Comment: The result differ because `availableIdentifiers` are not ordered.

Comment: @Sulthan that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem I was facing is that a given locale can contain multiple *unordered* currency symbols, e.g. `$` and `US$` for `en_US`.

This seems to do the trick:

```
func getSymbolForCurrencyCode(code: String) -> String? {
        let locale = Locale.availableIdentifiers.map { Locale(identifier: $0) }.filter { $0.currencyCode == code }
        return locale.map { $0.currencySymbol }.min(by: { $0!.count < $1!.count })!
    }
```

It returns the shortest available currency symbol of a locale, e.g. `$` and not `US$` for USD.